# I need to multiply two numeric updown values and display the result in textbox

Tags: c#

```
textBox5.Text= numericUpDown1.Value.ToString * numericUpDown2.Value.ToString;
```

but it not run successfully i got a error

> "Error    1   Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method
>   group' and 'method group'"

Comment: Your code doesn't _even_ compile. `ToString` is a method. That's why you need to use it as `ToString()`. And how do you think you can multiply two string values? If `Value` property returns numeric value (proper type for `*` operator of course), you can multiply them, convert to string and assign it to `textBox5.Text`. For example; `textBox5.Text= (numericUpDown1.Value * numericUpDown2.Value).ToString()`

Comment: `ToString` is a method, you forgot the brackets: `numericUpDown1.Value.ToString()`. But this does not help you at all, you need to take the value itself, not its `string` representation. Having the values multiplied, convert the result to a string.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that numericUpDown1.Value numericUpDown2.Value are multipliable type.

```
textBox5.Text= (numericUpDown1.Value * numericUpDown2.Value).ToString();
```

Comment: According to the MSDN, `NumericUpDown.Value` is a `decimal` property, therefore it **is** multiplyable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value(v=vs.110).aspx